# Is there a recommended approach to handle saving data in response to within-site navigation without onunload event?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, savechanges, onunload

**Preamble to scope my question:**

I have a web app (or site, this is an internal LAN site) that uses jQuery and AJAX extensively to dynamically load the content section of the UI in the browser. A user navigates the app using a navigation menu. Clicking an item in the navigation menu makes an AJAX call to php, and php then returns the content that is used to populate the central content section.

One of the pages served back by php has a table form, set up like a spreadsheet, that the user enters values into. This table is always kept in sync with data in the database. So, when the table is created, is it populated with the relevant database data. Then when the user makes a change in a "cell", that change immediately is written back to the database so the table and database are always in sync. This approach was take to reassure users that the data they entered has been saved (long story...), and to alleviate them from having to click a save button of some kind.

So, this always in sync idea is great, except that a user can enter a value in a cell, not take focus out of the cell, and then take any number of actions that would cause that last value to be lost: e.g. navigate to another section of the site via the navigation menu, log out of the app, close the browser, etc.

**End of preamble, on to the issue:**

I initially thought that wasn't a problem, because I would just track what data was "dirty" or not saved, and then in the onunload event I would do a final write to the database. Herein lies the rub: because of my clever (or not so clever, not sure) use of AJAX and dynamically loading the content section, the user never actually leaves the original url, or page, when the above actions are taken, with the exception of closing the browser. Therefore, the onunload event does not fire, and I am back to losing the last data again.

**My question, is there a recommended way to handle figuring out if a person is navigating away from a "section" of your app when content is dynamically loaded this way?**

I can come up with a solution I think, that involves globals and tracking the currently viewed page, but I thought I would check if there might be a more elegant solution out there, or a change I could make in my design, that would make this work.

Thanks in advance as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to follow up here, just in case anyone was interested. Turns out that my question was unnecessary.

Because I have my code set up to save the entered information in the change event for the input element, and since the change event only fires when the element in question loses focus, then if the user clicks anywhere else in my web app interface, that fires the change event for the input, and the data is saved.

The only exceptions are if they refresh the page, or they close the browser, but both of these events do result in an onunload event, meaning I can bind my save data function to that event and handle those cases.

So everything works as I hoped it would, and my confusion arose from a misunderstanding of when the change event would fire.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is normally overkill for site navigation. Unless there is a compelling reason to use AJAX , I would just make your navigation menu use good old links instead of AJAX calls.

AJAX is used to keep the user immersed in an application, without seeing the flicker, etc. of a full page refresh. However, if they are planning to navigate to another page, the full page refresh is expected (and therefore desirable).

Comment: That is an interesting point, and perhaps the AJAX for navigation is overkill, but it works very well. The nice thing is that it presents the user with an interface that has a genuine application feel rather than a website. The nav menu never has to reload in response to user interaction, no full page refresh as you mentioned. I think it makes a nice interface, but perhaps I may have to reconsider if I can't find another solution.